# after install kernel 5.4 bluetooth is not working

Tags: drivers, 20.04, nvidia, kernel, bluetooth

ubuntu version : **20.04**

kernel version: **5.4.0-100-generic**

Device : **Tp-link 500 Adapter**

After I downgrade the kernel for my Ubuntu from **5.13 to 5.4** the Bluetooth is not scanning any devices.

in kernel 5.13 working but Nvidia-340 driver is not supporting for this kernel so removed and install 5.4 recommended kernel.

I try all of these commands but had no luck.

```
sudo rfkill list 
    2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

 sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth


 sudo pkill -2 rtbt
 sudo rmmod rtbth
 sudo modprobe rtbth


 sudo rmmod btusb 
 sleep 1 
 sudo modprobe btusb



  lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'

 Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2357:0604 TP-Link 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 03f0:2641 HP, Inc 
[    0.157942] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[   15.881696] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   15.881722] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   15.881725] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   15.881727] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   15.881729] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   36.101199] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   36.101201] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   36.101206] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   83.965842] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   83.965850] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   83.965858] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  650.091628] audit: type=1107 audit(1646974456.866:50): pid=797 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" mask="send" name="org.bluez" pid=6062 label="snap.postman.postman" peer_pid=792 peer_label="unconfined"
[22838.709903] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000c999395d failed to resubmit (2)
[22838.709962] Bluetooth: hci0: failed to disable LE scan: status 0x1f
[23119.156946] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
[25871.673590] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[25871.673592] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[25871.673595] Bluetooth: DynamicAlloc pci_device_id table at 0x000000003d730359 with size 64
[25871.673596] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[25871.673596] Bluetooth: Convert: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
[25871.673597] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
[25871.673598] Bluetooth: pci_device_id: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
```

Comment: it is not updating the kernel from 5.13 to 5.4, its more like downdating.

Comment: @Irsu85 ok i changed upgrade to downgrade